# Java client connecting to PHP server for MySQL database with authentication

Tags: java, php, sql, client-server

I'm working on a Java application that asks the user for a username & password, and then connects to a server to verify the entered details. If they are valid, it will then ask the server (by requesting a PHP page) for data about that user. The user can modify this information using the application GUI, and changes are sent back to the server.

The main challenge is that the server doesn't use any Java. I need to make the server only use PHP, and it must be able to handle connections from different users simultaneously.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

EDIT: The application will be requesting multiple different scripts from the server for different types of data, and will need to send and receive quite a bit of data (Probably up to 500 pieces at a time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PHP file that accepts POST.

In your JAVA, try passing a custom header KEY:VALUE pair that's verified via your PHP file - or try to think of a more elaborate way.

Then, post along the username and password to the PHP file: `POST http://server.com/java-auth.php?user=username&pass=password` for pseudo example. Then, have that PHP file return a JSON-encoded string or a serialized string... or go super fancy, and encrypt it all with public/private keys.

Hope this helps :)